# Getting Django channel access in Celery task

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-channels

I have a Django app that's using channels to monitor a WebSocket to kick off backend tasks in Celery. It currently sleeps for a given amount and then returns true.

The problem is I don't know how to get access to the WebSocket from within the celery task so I can notify the UI once it's done.

```
celery==4.3.0
channels==2.2.0
Django==2.2.4
django-celery-results==1.1.2
djangorestframework==3.10.2
```

my tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
import time

@shared_task
def gotosleep(timeInSecs):
    time.sleep(timeInSecs)
    return True
```

My consumer.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json
from access.tasks import gotosleep

class AccessConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()


    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
       text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
       message = text_data_json['message']
        if message.isnumeric() == True:
            print("------------------------------------------------------")
            print(message)

            gotosleep.delay(int(message))

            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': 'We are dealing with your request'
            }))

        else:
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': 'Give me a number'
            }))
```

Any Ideas? Many Thanks

Comment: There are basically tons of questions on stackoverflow on how to send message through channels from outside the consumer like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461830/send-message-using-django-channels-from-outside-consumer-class. It is also in the docs https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers

Comment: @Ken4scholars: you are totally right and thanks for the links. But I understand moonraker cause the channel docs are a bit misleading. As they first mention channel layers as optional, and if one decides to leave them for now, one would miss the needed chapter in the docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@normic: Yes, I was struggling with the later addition of channel layers into my projects:

@Ken4scholars: Many thanks for the links. These prompted me to find what I was looking for.

For anyone else struggling:

## my tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
import time

from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@shared_task
def go_to_sleep_and_add(x,y):
    time.sleep(10)
    result = int(x)+int(y)
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'task_group_a',
        {
                'type': 'task_message',
                'message': result
        }
    )
    return result


@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

## my consumers.py:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json
from access.tasks import go_to_sleep_and_add    
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class AccessConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.room_group_name = "task_group_a"

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        num1 = text_data_json['message']['1']
        num2 = text_data_json['message']['2']
        if num1.isnumeric() and  num2.isnumeric()== True:

            go_to_sleep_and_add.delay(num1,num2)
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': 'We are dealing with your request'
            }))

        else:
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': 'Give me numbers'
            }))

    # Receive message from room group  
    def task_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

## my html page in Django/templates:

```
<!-- access/templates/access/room.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Access Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="access-log" cols="50" rows="5">Results &#13;&#10;</textarea><br/>
    Number 1:<input id="access-message-input" type="text" size="20"/><br/>
    Number 2:<input id="access-message-input2" type="text" size="20"/><br/>
    <input id="access-message-submit" type="button" value="Send"/>
</body>
<script>
    var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};
    var accessSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/access/' + roomName + '/');
    accessSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        document.querySelector('#access-log').value += (message + '\n');
    };

    accessSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Access socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    document.querySelector('#access-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#access-message-input');
        var messageInputDom2 = document.querySelector('#access-message-input2');
        COMPLETE = { '1': messageInputDom.value, '2': messageInputDom2.value}
        accessSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': COMPLETE
        }));

        messageInputDom.value = '';
        messageInputDom2.value = '';

    };

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but mine got resolved after using `channels-redis`

At first I used `InMemoryChannelLayer` and couldn't get past through it but after using `channels_redis.pubsub.RedisPubSubChannelLayer` everything works as a charm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).