# Django channels - unable to subscribe to groups

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm attempting to send consumers.py information to display on the client end outside of consumers.py.

I've referenced [Send message using Django Channels from outside Consumer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461830/send-message-using-django-channels-from-outside-consumer-class) this previous question, but the sub process `.group_send` or `.group_add` don't seem to exist, so I feel it's possible I'm missing something very easy.

**Consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class WSConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("appDel", self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

        self.render()
```

**appAlarm.py**

```
def appFunc(csvUpload):
    #csvUpload=pd.read_csv(request.FILES['filename'])
    csvFile = pd.DataFrame(csvUpload)
    colUsernames = csvFile.usernames
    print(colUsernames)

    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

    for user in colUsernames:
        req = r.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
        print(req)
        t = req.json()
        data = t['data']['email']
        print(user + " " + data)
        
        message = user + " " + data
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'appDel',
        {'type': 'render', 'message': message}
    )
```

It's throwing this error:

```
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group_send'
```

and will throw the same error for `group_add` when stripping it back more to figure out what's going on, but per the documentation [HERE](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#configuration) I feel like this should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone looking at this in the future, I was not able to use redis or even memurai in Windows OS due to cost. I ended up using server side events (SSE), specifically [django-eventstream](https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream), and so far it's worked great as I didn't need the client to interact with the server, for a chat application this would not work.

Eventstream creates an endpoint at `/events/` the client can connect to and receive a streaming http response.

Sending data from externalFunc.py:

```
send_event('test', 'message', {'text': 'Hello World'})
```

Event listener in HTML page:

```
var es = new ReconnectingEventSource('/events/');

es.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log(e.data);

    var source = new EventSource("/events/")

    var para = document.createElement("P");
    const obj = JSON.parse(event.data)
    para.innerText = obj.text;
    document.body.appendChild(para)

}, false);

es.addEventListener('stream-reset', function (e) {
}, false);
```